# how to extract objects from array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, orm

I realise that it was probably already asked but nothing I googled worked for me. I have an array of objects

```
const domain = [
                { 'domain': 'All Domains' },
                { 'domain': 'Active Domains' },
                { 'domain': 'Not Reviewed' },
                { 'domain': 'Not Seen' },
                { 'domain': 'Action Concluded' },
            ];
```

and I need to extract values to get

```
var newDomain = [
                   { 'domain': 'Active Domains' },
                   { 'domain': 'Action Concluded' },
                ];
```

I thought to use .map but I'm lost on how to use it.

Comment: What is the criteria of the result ? is it hardcoded ?

Comment: domain is hardcoded. I guess the second bit can be hardcoded too, i dont know what is the best way to make newDomain

Comment: Are you not satisfied with @brk's answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter`

```js
const domain = [{
    'domain': 'All Domains'
  },
  {
    'domain': 'Active Domains'
  },
  {
    'domain': 'Not Reviewed'
  },
  {
    'domain': 'Not Seen'
  },
  {
    'domain': 'Action Concluded'
  },
];
var newDomain = domain.filter(item => item.domain === 'Active Domains' || item.domain === 'Action Concluded');
console.log(newDomain)
```

Comment: Should you not mark this as dupe instead?

Comment: thank you @brk. unfortunately it doesnt let me upvote the answer, i dont have enough reputation :(